# How to fix Node js Package Manager?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, termux, npm-run

I am creating a website in next js on Android phone using termux.
All was working fine but from few days when I created new project from npx create-next-app and run using npm run dev it gives me this error

~/portfolio $ npm run dev                                                    > portfolio@0.1.0 dev

> next dev
> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000                                            info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin                                      Error: Unsupported platform: android                       at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-wasm-swc.js:84:31           at Object.downloadWasmSwc (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-wasm-swc.js:98:7)
> at async /data/data/com.termux/files/home/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js:114:13

I tried to update all packages but it didn't work

Comment: Do you have `swcMinify` enabled in your `next.config.js` file? I would try disabling it if so.

Comment: It didn't worked. Instead I just copied all files from node_modules/@next folder of my old working project and pasted it in new project node_modules/@next and It worked completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to fix this just go to the file at
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/portfolio/node_modules/next/dist/lib/download-wasm-swc.js go to line 98:7 now in the code where it says if process.platform === "linux" add || process.platform === "android" to that line save it then run npm run dev